# Videojs Control Bar not updating with video

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm using a `video.js` player with the `videojs-playlists` plugin, and I'm having issues with the `vjs-progress-control` bar (progress bar) and the `vjs-remaining-time vjs-time-control` (time remaining in video) element. The two both don't change or update with the video. They just stay in the starting position, and the "remaining time" displays "-0:00". Despite this, clicking on a point in the progress bar causes the video to skip to that point as expected, and moves the progress bar, but after that it stays in place. The remaining time stays at "-0:00". Also the progress bar moves in unexpected ways.

[This is an idea of what the progress bar looks like when skipping to a point in the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXN1C.png)

All the other elements such as pause/play, volume control, next video, previous video seem to work mostly fine but the play icon doesn't switch to the pause icon when the video is paused/playing.

What this seems to me like, is that the player isn't updating along with the video as it's running but I don't know why that would be.

HTML:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
    <source src='' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-playlist@4.2.6/dist/videojs-playlist.min.js"></script>

<script>
var player = videojs(document.querySelector('video'));

var videosrc = [{
  sources: [{
    src: 'https://swing-move.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/videos/9d71ad7faac2673078db3cf48ba4eea9.mp4?',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
}, {
  sources: [{
    src: 'https://swing-move.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/videos/93d36682fc7dcf93f905c211a37e6d18.mp4?',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
}, {
  sources: [{
    src: 'https://swing-move.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/videos/bba42660b54514f90c98343503ea4f4b.mp4?',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
}, {
  sources: [{
    src: 'https://swing-move.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/videos/0a34c7808ca1e357aca75898b1bef213.mp4?',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
}];

player.playlist(videosrc)
```

Perhaps someone with more experience with this plugin could point me in directions to troubleshoot this if the error in my code isn't abundantly obvious.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your findings.  There IS indeed a bug in VideoJS,in regard to progress-bar related handling. I'm just finishing up on some code that also demonstrates the issue, and I will post it sometime in the next week.

Comment: I should mention:  The bug is NOT in the plugin...my code does not use it.

Comment: @Dave Interesting, I'll be looking forward to that post. By not in the plugin you mean not in `videojs-playlists` correct? The bug is in `video-js`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The bug is in video-js itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but I just encountered this myself. Maybe it will be helpful to someone:

I solved the issue by taking out the `source` tag in the HTML. So, above, instead of

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
    <source src='' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

you can just try

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
</video>
```

instead. Your JS should still be able to add the source, and for whatever reason, that will make the time bar/progress bar advance as expected.